# Alterar tamanho fonte de acordo com dispositivo iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Tenho um App de frases e cada frase tem um tamanho diferente (de acordo com a quantidade de palavras) e em tablets como a resolução é a mesma do iphone 4s as frases extrapolam o tamanho reservado a elas e ficam por traz de um botão que tenho na tela (centralizado na parte de baixo do app), não exibindo seu conteúdo todo. É possível alterar o tamanho da fonte de acordo com o tipo de dispositivo? Ou qual seria a melhor solução para resolver tal problema? Vale ressaltar que em iPhones esse texto fica bem longe do botão o que torna inviável diminuir o texto sempre ou jogá-lo para cima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei criar uma variação, porém parece não ter resolvido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tiago, seria interessante você adicionar uns exemplos visuais do que acontece e trechos de código pro pessoal entender melhor o problema. Sobre a sua pergunta, acredito que a função sizeToFit pode resolver teu problema

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nessa função.. segue a imagem da renderização em ipads. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Existe sim uma solução, se chama "Auto Layout" você deve selecionar o texto e no inspetor do xcode você aciona uma regra para isso clicando no botão `+` da fonte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

veja que aparece os campos para que você escolha a largura e altura para a nova variação. os tamanhos você pode conferir abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

dessa forma basta que você selecione a opção desejada e veja como fica em seu app.

Comment: Olá Ramires, muito obrigado pela dica, mas acho que ainda falta algo, de uma olhada na minha pergunta, adicionei a imagem (figura 2) com as variações e ainda ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: você deve mudar a opção wR e hR para 14 e não para 20

Comment: Então, eu fiz isso, porém o texto já iniciava no tamanho 14 mesmo em telas grandes, dai pensei em fazer um wR e hR (Regular) com o tamanho normal (20) e uma outra com wC e hC (de compact) com o tamanho 14, porém não mudou em nada. Além de clicar no + e escolher os itens, tem que marcar mais alguma coisa?

Comment: qual o component você esta usando para essa frase? é uma label?

Comment: outra coisa, você está iniciando o seu projeto com qual tamanho de tela? é super recomendado começar pelo menor tamanho de tela que você quer atingir, e só depois passar para telas maiores.

Comment: Sim estou usando um Label. Como eu faço para iniciar com o menor tamanho de tela?

Comment: na parte inferior clicke na barra que tem "View as: iPhone 6" e escolha o tamanho da tela, lógico que no lugar de "iPhone 6" irá esta o. tamanho que você está usando. 
Uma segunda opção é você usar um text view no lugar de uma lábil, pois ele cria uma barra de rolagem.

Comment: Você conseguiu?

Comment: Não consegui amigo, com Label já tentei tudo isso ai e não vai. A solução que encontrei por hora foi limitar o numero de linhas na propriedade Lines, porém se o texto for maior ele vai ficar cortado.

Comment: Boa noite Tiago, se você quiser podemos marcar uma video chamada para tentar resolver junto, ficaria feliz em ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda amigo. Podemos tentar a video chamada sim, mas eu já me enchi desse problema, vou remodelar o visual todo do App.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seja possível ajustar com `Auto Layout`, como foi sugerido em outra resposta.

Para isso, seria bom garantir que o `bottomAnchor` da `Label` esteja ancorado ao `topAnchor` do botão, evitando que vá para trás dele.

Então, para mostrar todas as linhas da `Label` e garantir que caibam no espaço que ela possui:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;

// Faz com que a fonte reduza para caber no container
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

Caso queira evitar que a fonte reduza muito, é possível definir até quanto % do tamanho original ela pode reduzir:

```
// Permite reduzir até metade do tamanho original da fonte da label    
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

P.S.: Pensando em casos de frases muito extensas, há algumas alternativas para contornar, como utilizar um `UITextView` não editável/selecionável.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Caro amigo, a idéia é que realmente o autoLayout te ajude, porém como sua pergunta foi para saber qual o tipo de aparelho, segue a resposta:

Você pode determinar o aparelho da seguinte forma:

Para facilitar vou criar 2 structs.

Essa primeira pega dinamicamente o width e height do aparelho, determinando o max e min:

```
    public struct ScreenSize{
      static let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
      static let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
      static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
      static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    }
```

Essa segunda já possui as regras para determinar o tipo de aparelho usado:

```
    public struct DeviceType
    {
      static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS =  UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
      static let IS_IPHONE_5 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
      static let IS_IPHONE_6 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
      static let IS_IPHONE_6P = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
      static let IS_IPHONE_X = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    }
```

Um exemplo de seu uso seria:

```
    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {          
                // 4S ou anterior          
    }
```

Foram criados constantes static's para facilitar seu uso em suas classes.